# How do I start the screensaver with JXA?

Tags: macos, screensaver, javascript-automation

In the System Events scripting dictionary there is a suite called Screen Saver Suite, however I have been unable go the methods to run.

I have tried

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true


SystemEvents = Application('System Events') 


SystemEvents.ScreenSaver.start()
```